# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value When I use SnackBar in Get X Framework

Tags: android, flutter, dart, get, snackbar

I need to show message via snackbar using Get X Framework.
I tried source code like below

```
Get.snackbar('Need Distributor', 'Make Sure Set Up Route Plan', snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
```

When I run my source code then it throws an exception like the below code

```
Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 4476): #0      SnackbarController._configureOverlay (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:91:50)
E/flutter ( 4476): #1      SnackbarController._show (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:331:5)
E/flutter ( 4476): #2      GetQueue._check (package:get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart:42:47)
E/flutter ( 4476): #3      GetQueue.add (package:get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart:29:5)
E/flutter ( 4476): #4      _SnackBarQueue._addJob (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:357:31)
E/flutter ( 4476): #5      SnackbarController.show (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:63:27)
E/flutter ( 4476): #6      ExtensionSnackbar.snackbar (package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:465:18)
```

I have tried my project using android studio. using Get X framework.

Comment: Have you changed your MaterialApp into GetMaterialApp() ?

Comment: i use MaterialApp()

Comment: If you are using Get package and Get.snackbar you need to change the MaterialApp to GetMaterialApp.